# Can I write - sit parallel

Tags: meaning, phrases

I wrote this sentence -

> His name was criticized severely and now his name **sits parallel** with all sort of corruption.

I wrote this sentence. And I want to know what you think about the usage of "sit parallel" in this sentence? Is it understandable? If it's then what meaning you think of it?

Answer (score 1):

No.

First of all, "to be parallel to," as has been pointed out, means literally "to be next to but not touching" and figuratively "to be similar to," not "to be associated with."

> The road ran **parallel to** the beach for about five miles.
>
> She was living a life **parallel to** his own; they attended the same schools, ran with the same crowd, but never met.

Second of all, the most common preposition used with "parallel" in English, as seen in the examples above, is "to," not "with."

Third, the construction you've chosen, which compares one person's name to an abstract concept, is very limiting in its choice of verbs. "Associated with" is one of only a few verbs that can comfortably take a name as a subject and "corruption" as an object in this context.

You can either use this construction, with a verb like "associated":

> Now his name is **associated with** all sorts of corruption.

Or you can use a more parallel construction and have a choice of more colorful language:

> Now his name is yoked with Benedict Arnold's as a watchword of corruption.
>
> His corrupt practices are pressed from the same mold as those of other corrupt politicians we have seen over the years.

Comment: I also find the first part odd.  "His name was criticised..."   Surely not.  Surely **he** was criticised, not his name. Metemony be damned!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using  *sit parallel* in a figurative way to say that his name is now closely associated with al sort of corruption.

I'd probably say *his name sits parallel with the names of other corruptors*

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's understandable but not a usage that would normally be seen and, assuming I did determine the meaning correctly, would suggest "**is associated**" as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is certainly understandable, but I think it's a poor metaphor: *parallel* means "lying alongside **and never touching**".

And in English we do not normally say "his **name** was criticized" to mean that the person bearing the name was criticized. The **name** of one of the oldest and most prestigious civil-rights organizations in the US, the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People, has occasionally been criticized because it employs a now deprecated term for persons of color; but that does not imply criticism of the organization.